# R Shiny stop code execution until modal is closed

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog

I want to execute rest of  shiny app code only when modal dialog box is closed. How can I achieve this?

Here simple code:

```
# ui.R
actionButton("loadData", label = "Button", icon = icon("mail-forward"))

# server.R
observeEvent(input$loadData, {

  showModal(modalDialog(
    title = modal.title,
    textInput("newName", "Enter file name:", value = ""),
    easyClose = TRUE,
    footer = list(
      actionButton("confirmName", "OK"),
      modalButton("Cancel"))
  ))

  # ...code to be executed after modal is closed...

})
```

Answer (score 5):

Create an [event handler](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.5/observeEvent.html) that executes code when the OK action button has been clicked, and also closes the modal using [`removeModal`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.5/showModal.html).

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("loadData", label = "Button", icon = icon("mail-forward")),
  verbatimTextOutput("filename")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$loadData, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "title",
      textInput("newName", "Enter file name:", value = ""),
      easyClose = TRUE,
      footer = list(
        actionButton("confirmName", "OK"),
        modalButton("Cancel"))
    ))
  })

  output$filename <- eventReactive(input$confirmName, {
    message("Closing modal")
    removeModal()
    input$newName
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

There's an example of this in the docs: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/modalDialog.html

Comment: I don't think this achieves the desired behavior, as any code written after `output$filename <- ` will happily execute while the modal is still open